# odd css behaviour - Image inline not underneath

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got a twitter/facebook logo in the footer of my site.

My page code is:

```
<div class="layout-cell" style="width: 50%">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/mysite/" target="_blank" class="facebook-tag-icon"></a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mysite" target="_blank" class="twitter-tag-icon"></a>
</div>
```

My css is:

```
.facebook-tag-icon {
background:  url('mysite.co.uk/fb-off.png') no-repeat scroll;
min-height:32px;
min-width:32px;
display: block;
margin: 5px;
float: right;
}

.facebook-tag-icon:hover {
background:  url('http://mysite.co.uk/fb_on.png') no-repeat scroll;
}

.twitter-tag-icon {
background:  url('http://mysite.co.uk/twitter_off.png') no-repeat scroll;
min-height:32px;
min-width:32px;
display: block;
margin: 5px;
float: right;
}

.twitter-tag-icon:hover
{
background:  url('http://mysite.co.uk/twitter_on.png') no-repeat scroll;
}
```

And I want my fb icon to display on top of my twitter icon, however they currently show on the same line, side by side... How can I get them to display on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to the twitter icon:

```css
.facebook-tag-icon {
background:  url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/87941b98d114974b269cd65f361b605b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1') no-repeat scroll;
min-height:32px;
min-width:32px;
display: block;
margin: 5px;
float: right;
}

.twitter-tag-icon {
background:  url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/87941b98d114974b269cd65f361b605d?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1') no-repeat scroll;
min-height:32px;
min-width:32px;
display: block;
margin: 5px;
float: right;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-cell" style="width: 50%">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/mysite/" target="_blank" class="facebook-tag-icon"></a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mysite" target="_blank" class="twitter-tag-icon"></a>
</div>
```